# Convert XML data into table in mysql

Tags: mysql, xml

I have a XML data like this

```
<Root>
<Data>
    <Heading>Time Management</Heading>
    <Field>
        <Description>Prioritizing work</Description>
        <Control>RadioButton</Control>
        <Items>Yes,No</Items>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Description>Phase wise time schedule</Description>
        <Control>RadioButton</Control>
        <Items>Yes,No</Items>
    </Field>
</Data>
<Data>
    <Heading>Team Player</Heading>
    <Field>
        <Description>Collaborating with others</Description>
        <Control>RadioButton</Control>
        <Items>Yes,No</Items>
    </Field>
</Data>
<Data>
    <Heading>Leadership Quality</Heading>
    <Field>
        <Description>Confident Level</Description>
        <Control>RadioButton</Control>
        <Items>High, Medium, Low</Items>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Description>Trust Of Team</Description>
        <Control>RadioButton</Control>
        <Items>High, Medium, Low</Items>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Description>Conflict Management</Description>
        <Control>RadioButton</Control>
        <Items>High, Medium, Low</Items>
    </Field>
</Data>
<Data>
    <Heading>Handling Kit</Heading>
    <Field>
        <Description>Safe usage of tools</Description>
        <Control>RadioButton</Control>
        <Items>Yes,No</Items>
    </Field>
</Data>
<Data>
    <Heading>Problem Solving Ability</Heading>
    <Field>
        <Description>Finding alternatives</Description>
        <Control>RadioButton</Control>
        <Items>Yes,No</Items>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Description>Managing Independently</Description>
        <Control>RadioButton</Control>
        <Items>Yes,No</Items>
    </Field>
</Data>
<Data>
    <Heading>Class room Behaviour</Heading>
    <Field>
        <Description>Discipline</Description>
        <Control>RadioButton</Control>
        <Items>Yes,No</Items>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Description>Interest in work</Description>
        <Control>RadioButton</Control>
        <Items>Yes,No</Items>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Description>Homework completion</Description>
        <Control>RadioButton</Control>
        <Items>Yes,No</Items>
    </Field>
</Data>
<Data>
    <Heading>Quality of Work</Heading>
    <Field>
        <Description>Activity completion on time</Description>
        <Control>RadioButton</Control>
        <Items>Yes,No</Items>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Description>Minimizing errors </Description>
        <Control>RadioButton</Control>
        <Items>Yes,No</Items>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Description>Utilizing available resources</Description>
        <Control>RadioButton</Control>
        <Items>Yes,No</Items>
    </Field>
</Data>
<Data>
    <Heading>Student's field of focus</Heading>
    <Field>
        <Description>Science</Description>
        <Control>RadioButton</Control>
        <Items>Yes,No</Items>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Description>Technology</Description>
        <Control>RadioButton</Control>
        <Items>Yes,No</Items>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Description>Engineering</Description>
        <Control>RadioButton</Control>
        <Items>Yes,No</Items>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Description>Mathematics</Description>
        <Control>RadioButton</Control>
        <Items>Yes,No</Items>
    </Field>
</Data>
```

This xml is there in each row. I have to make analysis using this data. I tried **ExtractValue()** function. It takes huge amout of time a i have more than 500 rows (It will increase to thousands).

If i could extract the xml into a table, then i can analyse. Is there any way i can do that ? i cannot use Load XML infile, as i cannot dump into a file first and then take it back. Is there any other way ?